# Tomcat8_DHIS2 not starting

Tags: java, tomcat8, dhis-2

I installed and ran DHIS2 on tomcat 8 a week ago and everything was going fine. To start the tomcat server, I had to click on Tomcat8_DHIS2, wait for the cmd to stop running, then start the Tomcat8_DHIS2w. Everything was going fine until the Java version on my PC got updated. I changed the PATH environment variable, but still, it did not work.
What happens is that the Tomcat_DHIS2.exe simply does nothing. It blinks for a fraction of a second then nothing happens. Naturally, localhost:8080 does not work either.

Can anyone help me pinpoint the source of the problem, please? I can't seem to find anything on google or stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you are doing it on windows OS. It is recommended to use it on linux.
There are scores of bugs on windows installation.
Its very stable on linux OS.